# Reusing Xamarin.Forms.Application while LoadApplication in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, prism

How bad idea is to create application only once and use it all time when calling OnCreate in Android app:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
  ...
  if(FirstRun)
    _app = new App(new AndroidInitializer());
  LoadApplication(_app);
}
```

The application resumes much faster. I did not noticed any issues during basic tests. FirstRun and _app are static properties.
OnCreate is called again for new activity when previous activity was destroyed. It happens for example when exiting app with back button or changing theme to dark.

Comment: Do you notice any speed difference when debugger is not attached? (Run from device's home page.) I wouldn't expect OnCreate to be called again when "resume", so maybe what you are seeing is related to Hot Reload when running under debugger. I'd be hesitant to do anything "unusual" in the final release, so maybe this should be inside `#if DEBUG`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve It is definitely related to reusing the App instance. Please check edited question.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize those actions called OnCreate again, yet kept statics. I personally would be worried that there could exist some situation, perhaps only on certain Android devices, where quitting the app at the wrong moment leaves something in a bad state, such that full re-initialization is safer. Bottom line: Do that, and you are "on your own" - you are doing it a way that no one else is. Is it really worth that risk? Have you tested it on an actual device, launching from device's home page (so not running on debugger)? How much faster is the relaunch in that case?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have similar feelings about such solution but still hoping it is doable. Especially using Prism framework. My app is quite big platform and requires longer startup time. On older devices relaunch may be few seconds faster.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, a Xamarin Forms Application doesn't have an `OnCreate` method. An Android Activity has.

The activity's `OnCreate` is only called when `FirstRun` is `true` - when the activity's reused, the system calls `OnRestart` and `OnStart`, as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/activity-lifecycle/#activity-lifecycle-methods). If the activity get's destroyed, the `FirstRun` flag won't survive.

Comment: Xamarin Forms Application doesn't have an OnCreate method - thats right. I did not write any such thing. Please check edited question.